# Вытянуть текущее время просмотра на Youtube

Tags: javascript, xpath, youtube, youtube-api

Мне требуется помощь)

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы вытянуть текущее время просмотра со страницы просмотра видео YouTube.
Я понимаю, как пойти через XPATH, и если использовать XPATH, выглядеть это будет примерно следующим образом:
`//span[@class="ytp-time-current"]`.
Но текст внутри этого `span` обновляется каким-то не знакомым мне способом (то есть когда мышь не наведена на видео, текст не обновляется). Признаюсь, я не знаю javascript, jQuerry.

Как можно вытянуть текущее время просмотра со страницы? Что для этого нужно сделать? Простой XPATH не годится для этой цели. Нужно куда-то глубже лезть.
Благодарю!

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].currentTime`

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это js? Просто это выглядит, как готовое решение, только вот мне не понятно, что оно возвращает? Как оно работает. Я сейчас гуглю эту информацию, но буду благодарен, если пнёте в нужном направдении

Comment: `Я правильно понимаю, что это js?` — Да, это js. `... что оно возвращает?` — Об этом был вопрос: `Как можно вытянуть текущее время просмотра со страницы?`. Из-за этого выражения: "`... когда мышь не наведена на видео, текст не обновляется`", — я решил, что подойдёт решение, которое можно использовать с помощью консоли

Comment: Да, я смог через консоль осуществить это! Спасибо Вам, Вы действительно мне помогли! :)

Comment: Простите, но если Вы сможете уточнить - будет очень ценно для меня.
Я пытаюсь найти элемент на странице, в котором  находится `currentTime`, и как я понимаю, Ваш код вытягивает это значение как-то типа API, т.е. в коде страницы никакого `currentTime` нет. Но я нашел элемент `<video>`.
Хотелось бы уточнить вот почему. Ваш код вытягивает хорошо, но не всегда верно. Бывает, что нужно подставить `[1]`, чтобы он сработал правильно. Можно ли как-то усовершенствовать "селектор"?

Comment: По поводу индекса: видимо, это зависит от того, есть ли реклама перед видео. Но `currentTime` - свойство [элемента видео](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: Скорее всего не совсем от рекламы. `currentTime` от рекламы и от самого видео тянется под одним порядковым номером, если корректно так выразиться. Но особенность YT в том, что на странице есть несколько плееров (основной, мини-плеер и т.п.), видимо это сказывается
Благодарен Вам за ссылку. Изучу внимательно!